# How to Convert Multi-Page PDF files to Multi-Page Tiff with out installing any exe

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, tiff

i am doing a project to converting multi-page pdf file  to multi-Page Tiff image.

in my office i cant install any exe files... is there any free .net library is available to do this by adding reference itself...

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer I worked on this component at Software Siglo XXI)*

If you don't want to mess with Ghostscript API and need a quick working solution to convert PDF documents to raster images (PNG, JPG, ...), you could use **Super Pdf2Image Converter .NET**. It's available for both 32 and 64 bit and is very cheap and effective.

You can take a look here: http://softwaresigloxxi.com/SuperPdf2ImageConverter.html

For instance, here's a sample code for converting:

```
// Instantiate the component
Pdf2ImageConverter p2i = new Pdf2ImageConverter(pdfPath);

// Get page count of a PDF file
int pages = p2i.GetPageCount();

// Convert any page of PDF to image file (preserving aspect ratio)
GetImage(outputFileName, firstPage, lastPage, resolution, imageFormat)
```

The last sentence converts specifies pages to a single TIFF file image and save them to outputFileName.